# Get Roles with UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is there a way to get all the roles a user is in using their UserId (uniqueidentifier)? I know that I can use `Roles.GetRolesForUser(string username)`, but I don't have the username at that point, but do have the UserId. I could get the username, but was hoping I could circumvent that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, came up with my own solution, not sure if it is the best and haven't tested it yet, but theoretically it should work. If anyone has something better, please do share.

```
string userName = Membership.GetUser(userGuid).UserName;
var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName);
```